# Bivariate generating functions and diagonal like recurrences

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve recurrences of the type

$$a(n,m) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} a(n-k,k), \qquad a(n,0)= a(0,m)=1 \qquad (A_0)$$

with the help of generating functions, but I get stuck quite early on.
If I take the usual sum (neglecting the boundary condition for a while), I get

$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m \geq 0} a(n,m) x^n y^m = \sum_{n,m \geq 0} \sum_{k=0}^{m} a(n-k,k)x^n y^m \qquad (A_1)$$

If the summand would be $a(n,k)$, we'd be happy and that sum would simply be the convolution with the constant sequence, hence $f(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{1-y}$, however thats not the case.

How to proceed in such a case?

PS:
Is there even a general way to find the gf for linear recurrences summing over specific "paths", e.g. $a(n,m) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} a(n-ck,k), \quad c \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: So, you know what Riordan arrays are?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I looked into the theory and found it to be beautiful, however, is the original sequence even a proper riordan array (whose recurrence just involves terms in the row before)? I fail to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a convention that $a(n,m)=0$ when $n<0$ or $m<0$, and ignoring boundary conditions as you do, write
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} a(n-k,k)x^n = x^k \sum_{n\geq0} a(n,k)x^n = x^k [y^k]f(x,y),$$
where $[y^k]f(x,y)$ is the coefficient of $y^k$ in $f(x,y)$. Then you can sum further:
$$\sum_{0\leq k\leq m} y^m x^k [y^k] f(x,y) = \sum_{0\leq k} \frac{y^k}{1-y} x^k [y^k]f(x,y). $$
Now the sum over $k$ is just $f(x,xy)$, because it replaces every $y^k$ with $x^k y^k$, so this is
$$ \frac{f(x,xy)}{1-y}. $$

Replacing $a(n-k,k)$ with $a(n-ck,k)$ in the inner sum yields the inner sum
$$ \sum_{n\geq0} a(n-ck,k)x^k = x^{ck}[y^k]f(x,y), $$
using the same method as above. In the end, this gives
$$ \frac{f(x, yx^c)}{1-y}. $$

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping still for something being less than a  functional equation, but thats fine. (meta: sorry for not marking the question earlier)